# MVC 5 - include WebPack output into publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webpack, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC 5 with WebPack.

I have a "/dist" folder in my web project which is empty, but during compile I invoke WebPack and it creates output files for me. "/dest" will be populated with files which WebPack has created for me.

```
/dist
  /dist/script1.js
  /dist/script2.js
  etc...
```

How can I ensure that the "/dist" folder and all of its files are included in the publish output?

The web project publishes just fine, but the /dist folder is missing from it.

Including the files into the solution doesn't seem like the right answer. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the dist folder to the project by adding to the csproj file :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="dist/**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

this will include the dist folder and all its files in the project, and since it's declared as content it will also be included in the deployement.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm. The folder shows up in Visual Studio, but is not in source control. I'll probably add it to my .tfignore file just to be safe though.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work in cases where webpack is generating the files during the build process.  MSBuild doesn't see the files in the included directory before they are generated, so the publish doesn't include them.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below in the "Project" element of your publishing profiles (PublishProfiles\*.pubxml)

I found this earlier somewhere, probably on StackOverflow, but can't find the link now.

This works fine (for me) with webpack output, unlike the accepted answer.

```
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <Message Text="=== CustomCollectFiles ===" Importance="high" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <_CustomFiles Include=".\dist\**\*" />
        <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
            <DestinationRelativePath>dist\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
        </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
        CustomCollectFiles;
        $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>

    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
        CustomCollectFiles;
        $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```